# Cross Origin call is not allowing in browser

Tags: angularjs, spring, cors

I am trying to call one application to another where I am getting and error as "Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response." and in my back-end I have used the following code as mentioned below

```
     List<String> originList = Arrays.asList(origins.trim().split("( )*,( )*"));
    String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
    if (originList.contains(origin)) {
        originAllow = origin;
    } else {
        originAllow = originList.get(0);
    }
     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originAllow);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, accept, authorization");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
```

In originAllow I am passing the url which I am trying to access but I am getting the below error,

```
     XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<<url>>. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Please find the browser request and response header,
      Response Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, content-type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
    Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
    Connection:close
    Content-Length:0
    Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Application-Context::8080
```

```
    Request Header
    Accept:/
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:myrestapi-dev
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

OPTIONS <>?page=0&search_param=test&size=10,desc HTTP/1.1
Host: myrestapi-dev
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6

I am running application in localhost:port and the other application is using deployed url where the protocol,host are different.

Please let me know Is there anything I need to add to access the url from ui(angular) for authorization moreover it is working in other browser but not in chrome

Comment: does response is of httpResponse or ServletResponse??
kindly provide request header as well from browser.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, content-type for reponse and Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, x-requested-with for request is mentioned and in backend I have added "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type, accept, authorization" but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

this is because your server isn't allowing the authorization header.
To address it:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, authorization");
```

should help you. as I am not sure about your backend I need to explain a bit more. 
This is because it is up to the server to specify that it accepts cross-origin requests (and that it permits the `Content-Type` request header).Moreover,  You need to make AJAX call from the same domain or make server-side changes, allowing requests from external domains.To address this you need to make changes in headers at http://yourdomain.com by allowing your external domain in headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

1- [ref1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

2- [ref2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

**Possible solution in AngularJs.** : Using JSONP with Angular

The AngularJS $http service has a built-in method called "jsonp".

```
var url = "some REST API Url" + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
       // whatever 
    });
```

Also, the url had to be appended with ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK.

I am going to expand this solution using JSONP

```
exampleurl = 'http://wikidata.org/w/api.php?whatever....&format=json'

 //Number 1 : 
 $.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: exampleurl ,
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  // do whatever
});
//Number 2 : 
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: exampleurl + '&callback=?',
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  // do whatever
});
//Number 3 : 
$.getJSON( exampleurl + '&callback=?', function(data) {
  // do whatever
});
```

more information

1- [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

2-[$.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: After adding the content-type also I am getting the same error and I have already provided the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://<url> . Please let me know Is there any other changes required

Comment: I have updated my post. but I believe this is server-side problem however you can go ahead with new solution in Angular.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * - this is almost always a bad idea because it opens up your site to requests from *anywhere*. Unless you're absolutely sure you want this then it's much more secure to only allow origins that you trust.

Comment: @DaveMongoose indeed, that's the bad practice.